# Can i write standalone testcases in robot framework?

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

I want to have testcases on seperate files that can be imported into the suites files.
Is there any way to do this in robot or any other python automation frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't import a test case into a test suite *file*, but you can certainly put one test case in a test suite file, and place many such files in a folder. That folder can then be treated like a test suite without having to import anything.

Given the following file structure:

```
my_test_suite/
|-- test1.robot
|-- test2.robot
`-- test3.robot
```

You can run `my_test_suite` directly from robot:

```
$ robot my_test_suite
```

If you want to add some metadata such as a suite setup, create a file named `__init__.robot` inside of `my_test_suite`. In there you can put a `*** Settings ***` table just like you can in normal test suite files.

Comment: is the log files of each robot file generated seperately or one file will get generated.
I want to have the logs of each testcase seperately and didn't want them in html format. As my execution environment is linux based.

Comment: @ASUR: you get one log file for every time you run the robot or pybot command. If you want one per file, you have to run each test separately. All of this information is in the user guide.